# how to make a custom button menu for iphone app ?

Tags: iphone, menu

I want to create a custom menu, in the buttom of the screen, like this one :

[image: custom menu]

what is the best ui class should I use, I think it's not a Tabbar ? Toolbar may be ?

Any piece of code help to customize will be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is by manipulating UIButtons.

Follow those steps:

- add UIButtons in IB
- connect proper actions to the following methods in your UIViewController class

.

```
-(IBAction)setTabOne{
    [self resetButtons];
    [tabBTOne setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabOne_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tabBTOne setSelected:YES];
    [tabBTOne setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

-(IBAction)setTabTwo{
    [self resetButtons];
    [tabBTTwo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabTwo_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tabBTTwo setSelected:YES];
    [tabBTTwo setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
...

-(void)resetButtons{
    [tabBTOne setSelected:NO];
    [tabBTTwo setSelected:NO];

    [tabBTOne setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabOne.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tabBTTwo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabTwo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [tabBTOne setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [tabBTTwo setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new @ iphone dev. If I want to get those buttons appears in all my views, as if they were a tababar items, what I have to do? MAy be adding a view pragmaticallay with the size i want and add it to the main view ?

Comment: You should create two views. One view will be your custom tab view and the other will be your content vie. So that you create your tab view only once and just reload the content view.

Answer (score 2):

Just put 5 UIButton's with correct frame and correct UIImage for the button state.